# Best practice subscribing to pipeline again after completion in Combine

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have a Pipeline which is waiting for a message and handle it afterwards. When I'm done I would like to restart the Pipeline and wait again for an incoming InitialMessage. What is the best practice for doing this? Feedback is highly appreciated.

```swift
        self.incomingInitialMessage()
            .flatMap { self.handleTransmission(for: $0, transmissionProvider: $1) }
            .subscribe(on: self.transmissionQueue)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] completion in
                   ....
                }, receiveValue: { _ in })
            .store(in: &self.disposeBag)
```